# returning to the start of a while loop in a binary search

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, while-loop, binary-search

I have a binary search to search a list of emails from a user input. However when the user inputted email isnt found in the list I want the user to be able to enter another time. However I dont know how to return it to the start of the while loop again.
Here is my Code:

```
def BubbleSort(logindata):
NoSwaps = 1
N = len(logindata)
logindata = list(logindata)
while NoSwaps == 1:
    Count = 1
    NoSwaps = 0
    for Count in range(N-1):
        if logindata[Count] > logindata[Count+1]:
            temp = logindata[Count]
            logindata[Count] = logindata[Count+1]
            logindata[Count+1]=temp
            NoSwaps=1
return tuple(logindata)

def BinarySearch(logindata,email):
    First=0
    Last=len(logindata)-1
    ItemFound = False
    SearchFailed = False
    while ItemFound == False or SearchFailed == False:
        Midpoint = (First + Last) // 2
        if logindata[Midpoint][0] == email:
            ItemFound = True
            print("Email Found")
            break

        elif logindata[Midpoint][0] > email:
            Last = Midpoint - 1
            print("Not Found")

        else:
            First = Midpoint + 1
            print("Not Found")

        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logindata=["tom@gmail.com","Password1"],["harry@gmail.com","Password2"],["jake@gmail.com","Password3"]
    logindata=BubbleSort(logindata)
    print(logindata)
    email=input("Enter username")
    BinarySearch(logindata,email)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the part you need to repeat in another while loop:

```
email=input("Enter username")
BinarySearch(logindata,email)
```

to:

```
while True:
    email=input("Enter username")
    res = BinarySearch(logindata,email)
    if res:
        break
print("Done")
```

and work with the return value of your `BinarySearch` function.

You also need to change the implementation of `BinarySearch` to return the appropriate values. Also, your condition is faulty, binary searching is ends when `First <= Last`, you can drop the other flags you're using:

```
def BinarySearch(logindata,email):
    First=0
    Last=len(logindata)-1
    while First <= Last:
        Midpoint = (First + Last) // 2
        if logindata[Midpoint][0] == email:
            print("Email Found")
            return True   
        elif logindata[Midpoint][0] > email:
            Last = Midpoint - 1
        else:
            First = Midpoint + 1
    print("Not found")
    return False
```

You shouldn't be printing `Not Found` whenever one of the else clause is executed, it hasn't been found *yet* since the search hasn't rerminated. Print that out in the end, after the `while` loop of `BinarySearch` has been exited.